# x11vnc icon in panel after autostart

Tags: lubuntu, icons, vnc, lxde, autostart

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04.

If I run command `sudo x11vnc -auth...` in terminal, the `x11vnc server` starts and it shows x11vnc icon in bottom panel (next to the clock). However, if I put this command to startup (`/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`), no icon shows up, so the user has no idea when and if someone connects to it.

Basically what I wish is some indicator for user to see when someone connects to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sudo x11vnc -auth...` needs to authenticate via the terminal, putting a `sudo` command in an autostart script (which is not connected to the terminal) you are guaranteed to fail.

Nothing in my reading of `man x11vnc` leads me to believe it must be started via `sudo`.

Comment: I mean yes, in the autostart file i put it without sudo, and it authenticates and launches fine. The only difference is the icon thingy.